# How to get shinyModals triggered by same event to show one after another?

Tags: r, shiny

I have two `shinyModals` that are triggered by the same event. When I trigger the event, modal 2 pops up and when "dismiss" is clicked modal 1 never shows up. I can tell by the print statements that both modal codes should have run. How can I get modal 1 to show up and then modal 2 to show up? As a note, in my real code the input doesn't always trigger two modals so I can't always rely on an input from one modal to trigger the other.

here is a demo of my problem

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message 1",
        "This is an important message!"
      ))
      print("modal 1 triggered")

      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message 2",
        "This is an important message!"
      ))
      print("modal 2 triggered")
    })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option - not sure if this best suits your needs however.

You can update the footer from a modalButton to an actionButton. And then create another observeEvent based on the actionButton. So when you close out of the first modal, the second modal will then appear.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message 1",
        "This is an important message!",
        footer = tagList(actionButton("close", "Dismiss")) # add actionButton
      ))
      print("modal 1 triggered")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$close, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message 2",
        "This is an important message!"
      ))
      print("modal 2 triggered")
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi @Jamie, thanks for the suggestion. It's a good answer but in my case it wont always work because the number of modals depends on the input in my real case.

Comment: I see - could you share a reprex that's more similar to your use case? I think it could be possible performing the above dynamically depending on the input.